# How can CPU utilization be between 0 and 100 percent

Tags: cpu, computer-science, cpu-usage, cpu-architecture, microprocessors

Please forgive my ignorance on such topics, but I was wondering a CPU has instruction pointer (IP) and so can either be using that IP or not use it (IDLE)..

So CPU utilization can be either 0(assuming idle task is doing nothing or just while(1)) or it can be 100...

What do they mean when CPU utilization is 30 or 40 percent.

How is this calculated.

Comment: When you execute 20bln instrucitons/second for every single one of them the CPU is at 100%, the time between them - at 0%. So much is true. But you couldn't possibly read a CPU indicator 20bln times per second, so you average the time of 100%s and those of 0%s. And this is simplistic because CPU frequency can vary itself, so those 100% at 20% frequency.... ahhh nvm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's for a given time period. For example, in the last second, what percentage of time was spent doing something, and what percentage of time was idle. You are correct that at any given instant the CPU can be thought of as either doing something or not.

Although not focusing on a simple percentage, the Wikipedia article on [load](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Load_(computing)) gives a simple overview of what goes into calculating how much work a computer is doing.

Answer (score 1):

On most machines, the CPU is always running.   The idle% is the time it's just waiting for useful work to do.

Think of it like the person at the register at Burger Barn.  They're standing there the whole time, but if there is no customer ordering then they are idle.  If in their 100 minute shift, if somebody is in front of them 73 of those minutes, then the cpu utilization is 73%.

Comment: not necessarily true. there's HLT instruction, so the CPU can actually be stopped, usually with a timer set to revive it after a short period of time to check if more work has shown up

Comment: You say "not running", I say "taking a long time to execute the HLT instruction". :)